# Can I have the get and post requests in the same app route?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to Python and currently doing a task on WTForms and SQLAlchemy in Flask Framework. I keep getting this error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rating,' yet I have it captured in class Movie. I have searched the whole of Stackoverflow but can't find the solution.

Below is my code:

server.py.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'The Key'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///top_10_movies.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Movie(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    movie_title = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    rating = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    ranking = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    review = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Movie %r>' % self.movie_title


with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

    new_movie = Movie(movie_title="Phone Booth",
                      year=2002,
                      description="Publicist Stuart Shepard finds himself trapped in a phone booth, pinned down by an extortionist's sniper rifle. Unable to leave or receive outside help, Stuart's negotiation with the caller leads to a jaw-dropping climax.",
                      rating=7.4,
                      ranking=10,
                      review="My favourite character was the caller.",
                      img_url="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/tjrX2oWRCM3Tvarz38zlZM7Uc10.jpg"
                      )
    db.session.commit()


class RateMovieForm(FlaskForm):
    new_rating = StringField('Your Rating Out of 10 e.g. 7.5', validators=[DataRequired()])
    new_review = StringField('Your Review', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Done')


@app.route("/")
def home():
    the_movie = Movie.query.all()

    return render_template("index.html", the_movie=the_movie)


@app.route('/update', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def update():
    form = RateMovieForm()
    movie_id = request.args.get("id")
    movie = Movie.query.get(movie_id)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        movie.rating = form.new_rating.data
        movie.review = form.new_review.data
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template("edit.html", movie=movie, form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Index.html code

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

{% block styles %}
  {{ super() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:300,400,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}My Top 10 Movies{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="heading">My Top 10 Movies</h1>
  <p class="description">These are my all time favourite movies.</p>
   
  <div class="card" >
      {% for movie in the_movie %}
    <div class="front" style="background-image: url({{movie['img_url']}});">
        <p class="large">{{movie['ranking']}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div>
    <div class="title">{{movie['movie_title']}} <span class="release_date">{{movie['year']}}</span></div>
        <div class="rating">
            <label>{{movie['rating']}}</label>
          <i class="fas fa-star star"></i>
        </div>
          <p class="review">{{ movie['review']}}</p>
        <p class="overview">
            {{movie['description']}}
            </p>

          <p>{{movie.id}}</p>
        <a href="{{url_for('update', id = movie.id)}}" class="button">Update</a>
        <a href="#" class="button delete-button">Delete</a>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container text-center add">
<a href="#" class="button">Add Movie</a>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I comprehend that the "**None"** error arises because the code "**movie_id = request.args.get("id")**" was unable to obtain the "id" from the index.html file.

What modifications should I make to this code to retrieve both the "id" (a 'GET' request) and the form data (a 'POST' request)?

Can I capture the "id" and form data in the same "update" route? If not, what is the solution to fix the 'None' issue?

Comment: Anyone to help me with this?

Comment: It helps if your question include a [mcve] -- *runnable* code that reproduces the problem. If you're asking a Python question, that means making sure your code includes the necessary `import` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I included the '**id=movie_id**' in the '**action**' URL link in '**edit.html**, instead of just the '**index.html**.' It worked. Here is the code:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block styles %}
  {{ super() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:300,400,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Edit Movies{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="heading"> Movie Title</h1>
    <p class="description">Edit Movie Rating</p>
  </div>
<form action="{{ url_for('rating_update', id=movie.id)}}" method="POST">
 {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```